# Ways to fight black mold

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, mycology

Is it possible to introduce a microorganism to a colony of black mold that will kill off the black mold entirely and permanently? Is there a common microorganism that likes to eat them and is harmless to us?

In other words, I ask if there's a way to get rid of the mold biologically, maybe a different mold that at least won't stink?

Alternatively, will getting a UV lamp to shine in the opening once in a while be an optimal solution?

I also read that copper sulfate is a popular fungicide with plantations, will it kill and prevent the mold from coming back? Could this ruin the AC with corrosion or be harmful to people if it will be airborne?

I ask this because I have black mold in my AC and I can't take it apart and disinfect it.

PS: it's probably [Aspergillus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspergillus#Commercial_importance), they're black and make these white structures like in this picture: [image]

Comment: I assume by "AC" you mean air conditioner.  What type of unit is it (car, home...?)  Why can't you take it apart to clean it?

Comment: Yes it's an air conditioner, it's a home unit. first of all, it's has a copper pipe and power cable that's connecting to the outside unit that I don't know how to disconnect properly so I could take it down. Secondly, it's built such that the fan part is really inside so taking it out means that I'll have to take out a lot of other parts fist. I don't know how to do it and I'm too afraid of breaking it in the process. @augurar

Comment: Frankly, I would suggest spraying it with some old fashioned water and vinegar. Creating an acidic environment is a pretty good mold treatment in the home. You should be able to tell if it's working- the color will fade as the mold dies. (Just unplug it first!)

Comment: @chauxvive I'm afraid this will stink more than the mold...

Comment: Bleach, borax and vinegar are good methods for fighting black mold. Don't work with bleach in the ventilation or mix it with anything! If you go w/ vinegar, you can mix salt into your solution for added effect. Borax is toxic if swallowed, as well, so vinegar is the safest option, and the smell will dissipate.

Comment: Well won't salt make it corrosive? I can order copper sulfate instead, it's pretty cheap. @Kendall

Comment: Uhh, well you're right, if it's something like stainless steel both salt and bleach would have some corrosive properties. Just be careful with the copper sulfate, too, especially in ventilation because that stuff isn't very good to get on your or in you, either. I'm not 100% in the know about cons for copper sulfate, though!

Comment: interesting question, but yet without the expected answer. The new gene editing tools might bring some hope. But until that, the most rational and effective way seems to involve Chlorine Dioxide gas (which kills -deactivates- the spores). But it's far from easy to deal with since the gas has to be produced when needed as a high concentration of the gas makes it explosive.

Answer (score 2):

I write this as an answer instead of a comment because I don't have the reputation to do otherwise (frustrating!) even to edit my answer-which-is-now-a-comment

A weak vinegar solution (maybe 1:1 ratio water and vinegar) will solve your problem and will not stink up your home. Vinegar smell evaporates very quickly and are great for areas you can't reach easily to clean by hand. I promise your AC won't smell like egg salad.

[Here's the first mold-cleaning with vinegar article I could find, there are plenty more where that came from](http://blacktoxicmolds.com/vinegar-kill-mold.php)

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try.